# Why this pthread code just hangs?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Following code snippet is written to print even number with one thread and odd number with other thread.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIMIT 100

int counter;

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* function(void *p)
{
    int expected = *(int *)p;
    while(expected < LIMIT) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
        while (counter != expected);
            printf("%d\n", counter++);
        expected += 2;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    };
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int counter = 0;
    int expected_0 = 0, expected_1 = 1;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, function, (void *)&expected_0);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, function, (void *)&expected_1);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

But when execute it shows an output of 0 and hangs

```
amit@ubuntu:~$ gcc -pthread even_odd.c 
amit@ubuntu:~$ ./a.out 
0
```

Could any one please point me out what is going here?

Also would there be a better logic to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

It is a classic case of mutex deadlock.

Let's see the details:

Here you created two threads sequentially, first one expecting `counter` to be 0 and the second one expecting `counter` to be 1.Then each one will increase counter by one and that make another thread's expected value.

Now it is not necessary that if you create thread `thread1` before thread `thread2` then thread `thread1` will always execute before thread `thread2`. This totally depends on you OS scheduler and you have minimal control on it.

So when `thread2` starts executing before `thread1`, it will acquire the `mutex1` and will start waiting in `while (counter != expected);` statement. Now when `thread1` starts excecuting, it will be blocked by `mutex1` as it is already aquired by `thread2`. Now, there is no one left to update `counter`. This will cause the deadlock.

You should use following code as the thread  function();

```
void* function(void *p)
{
    int expected = *(int *)p;
    while(expected < LIMIT)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
        if (counter == expected) {
            printf("%d\n", counter++);
            expected += 2;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    };
}
```

Here

- **I am locking mutex whenever I want to read or write the global
  variable *counter*. This prevents race condition.**
- **I am releasing mutex without busy waiting inside locked mutex for the
  same variable. This prevents deadlock.**

Comment: Reading `counter` outside the mutex lock is a data race, so undefined behaviour.

Comment: Not only that, you left the `;` after the `while ()` so your threads will both enter an infinite loop accessing `counter` without a mutex.

Comment: @Sunil see my answer, I figured out why the loop is still infinite, but locking the mutex before the inner `while ()` loop is correct.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing out the race condition. Updating my code as per your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems here.

The main one is that when a thread should wait for `counter` to reach its `expected` value, it doesn't unlock the mutex to allow the other thread to proceed.  This fixes that (add `<stdbool.h>` and compile as C99):

```
void* function(void *p)
{
    int expected = *(int *)p;
    while(expected < LIMIT)
    {
        bool my_turn = false;
        while (!my_turn)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
            my_turn = (counter == expected);
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
        printf("%d\n", counter++);
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
        expected += 2;
    };
```

The code above locks the mutex to check the counter, then unlocks it again and loops if the counter hasn't reached the expected value, so the other thread can run. It then locks the mutex again to access `counter` again.

Another problem is calling `exit(0)` which causes both threads to exit as soon as one of them finishes. You probably want to just return from the function instead:

```
    return NULL;
}
```

Another way to write the loop would be:

```
        while (true)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
            if (counter == expected)
                break;
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
        }
        printf("%d\n", counter++);
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
        expected += 2;
```

This is slightly more complicated to understand, but avoids unlocking and re-locking the mutex when the counter has reached the expected value. Instead it breaks out of the loop leaving the mutex locked, prints the value, then unlocks the mutex.